# SQL multiple combine of and and or

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]I have 2 tables `Invoices` and `moneyIn`
i have the query:

```
SELECT
moneyIn.id,
moneyIn.TransactionNo,
moneyIn.`Date`,
moneyIn.Customer,
moneyIn.Amount,
FROM moneyIn
```

and i want the sum of amount to be shown in invoices where the `customer` ` is the same in both tables and the date of moneyIn is later than the date of invoices and ( TranscationNo in moneyIn is same with transcationNo in Invoice OR TranscationNo in moneyIn is Null)
i made this query :

```
SELECT
Invoices.id,

Invoices.`Date`,
Invoices.TranscationNo
Invoices.Customer,
Invoices.SaleAmount,

Invoices.Commission,

Invoices.Freight,

Invoices.Total,

(select IFNULL(SUM(moneyIn.Amount),0) FROM moneyIn WHERE Invoices.Customer =moneyIn.Customer AND Invoices.`Date`< moneyIn.`Date` 
AND ( Invoices.TranscationNo=moneyIn.TranscationNo or moneyIn.TranscationNo is null  )
)AS `TTlTransfert`
FROM Invoices

LEFT outer JOIN moneyIn ON Invoices.Customer = moneyIn.Customer
GROUP BY Invoices.TranscationNo
ORDER BY Invoices.id DESC
```

but this still show sum of amounts earlier than invoices
ANd i want to show only amounts from moneyIn that its date is later than the date of Invoices
please help
 I want the result to be something like:

```
moneyIn             
id  customer    TransactionNo   date    Amount
1   a   dddd    12/19/2016  100
2   a   dd55    11/10/2016  300
3   a       10/18/2016  5000
4   b   dd4 12/19/2016  1000
5   b   d5  8/11/2016   2000


        Invoices

id  customer    TransactionNo   Date    moneyIn
1   a   dddd    12/16/2016  5100
2   a   dd55    11/9/2016   300
3   a   65655   12/20/2016  0
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I did some work for you http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92767/3 please provide data for invoices table to get any result

Answer (score 0):

Please provide raw data sample and expected result, but so far here is my attempt:

```
SELECT
  Invoices.id,
  Invoices.`Date`,
  Invoices.TranscationNo,
  Invoices.Customer,
  Invoices.SaleAmount,
  Invoices.Commission,
  Invoices.Freight,
  Invoices.Total,
  SUM(moneyIn.Amount) AS `TTlTransfert`
FROM Invoices
LEFT JOIN moneyIn 
ON Invoices.Customer = moneyIn.Customer
   AND Invoices.TranscationNo = moneyIn.TranscationNo
   AND Invoices.`Date`< moneyIn.`Date`
GROUP BY Invoices.id, Invoices.TranscationNo
ORDER BY Invoices.id DESC
```

Comment: @YahiaBaibathat is not raw that is images. And you did not post expected result set